# Swift2 iOS -Logging a current user out and creating a new user keeps the old user's defaults for the new user

Tags: ios, swift, boolean, nsuserdefaults, backend

I'm using the simulator for my project. When a user is logged in I'm using `NSUserDefaults` to determine which level they will go to. For i.e.

Jack downloads my app, creates an account, starts on level 1, buys some magic and since he bought the magic he can now skip level 1. Jack is now on level 2 and logs out of the game. Once Jack logs out and logs back in he will now land on level 2.

Inside the the LevelOneVC there is a buyMagic button for the magic purchase/level skip.

Inside the SignInVC I use `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey` to determine if that magic was bought, which in this case it's `true` and that will determine which level to send Jack to. That bool value is accessed inside a signInButton.

Jill is friend of Jack's, she borrows his phone, creates an account, as soon as she logs in she lands on level 2. She should land on level 1 since she is a different user and clearly has a different `Firebase uid` then Jack (I printed them to make sure).

I'm using `Firebase` as a backend which successfully logs users in and out and they all get different `uid's`. However since I'm using the simulator it seems that the `NSUserDefault` values are being recorded and no matter which user logs in, they will all get the previous users values.

I also tried changing the `bool` back to false in the SignUpVC but all that did was once Jill logged out and Jack logged back in he started at level 1 again.

FYI let me clarify that the only value I'm saving in `NSUserdefaults` is wether or not they bought the magic and nothing like their email or purchase info etc.

I guess these questions would lend itself to any other device specific info such as a specific background color or font a user would be able to specify for my app. I wouldn't think that would be `server side data` and I would instead save those in `NSUserDefaults`.

**Should I save this info of wether or not they bought the magic in NSUserDefaults or in my Firebase backend? Where am I going wrong?**

**Is Jill landing on level 2 because she's using the same exact device?**

**Outside of using a backend, how can I get it so that if multiple users are using the same device and once 1 logs out and the other logs in the previous values won't be saved**

*Btw I also tried using a `singleton class` with a `global bool variable` but the same problem occurred. I didn't include it*

AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
      //this is initially a false value
      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("wasMagicBought")
}
```

SignInVC

```
SignInController: UIViewController{

let magicPurchased = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("wasMagicBought")

@IBAction func signIn(sender: UIButton){
   //firebase method to sign user in and handler with async_brings them inside based off of the NSUserDefaults value
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
     if magicPurchased{
       //function to bring them to level 2
    }else{
      //function to bring them to level 1
      //If it's their first time making an account or if they made an account but never made it pass level 1 without buying magic this should always run i.e. Jill.
    }
   }
  }
}
```

LevelOneVC

```
LevelOneController: UIViewController{

@IBAction func buyMagic(sender: UIButton){
     self.skipLevelOne()
   }

   func skipLevelOne(){
    self.buyMagic()
    //since they bought the magic I now log it in NSUserDefaults as true
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "wasMagicBought") 
   }

 func buyMagic(){
    //code for the user to purchase the magic allows them to skip to level 2
   }
}
```

SignUpVC
SignUpController: UIViewController{

```
@IBAction func signUp(sender: UIButton){
     //code to sign user up
     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "wasMagicBought")
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think data of this type (purchases) should be saved by your backend. It's not safe to store them locally for many reason: one of them is that you need to delete this key anytime a new user log in and this means that you'll loose all the data of the previous one.

By doing as Matt says, if `Jack` will sign in again, will start from the level 1 again.

You can decide whether to keep this data on Firebase or you can build a more complex data to store, like a dictionary which has as key the user id

```
purchaseDictionary: [String: Bool] = [
    jackId: true,
    jillId: false
]
```

If you decide the `NSUserDefaults` way, you should consider that, if `Jack` will uninstall the app or change iPhone, he will loose any data.

Answer (score 1):

A registered user's game reach level should be updated to backend API. You should never depend on maintaining them in app itself.

```
if let gameLevel = user["gameLevel"] as? Int {  // user is a payload received from API
    // if gameLevel is 2, user should be moved to 2nd level
    // and similarly check if magicBought is true
}
```

In Swift 3, You either remove that value from NSUserDefaults or change it to false, when the user logs out

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "wasMagicBought")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() // use this to save the updates immediately
```

or

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "MyKey")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: Ahhhh I never knew about that removeObjectForKey() method. I'll try it in a few. Thanks

Comment: Thanks but Luca D'Alberti was right, it brought Jack back to level 1. I tried and it will reset anyone who logs out to level 1. if magicPurchased{
       //this will never run
    }else{
      //this will always run
    }. The starting value on app launch will always be false.

Comment: What will happen jack sign in another phone? Do you keep track of the user?

Comment: Oj thank you for the suggestion on me using the backend. I never programmed for a game before so this is all new to me. The synchronize didn;t work but if you change your answer to say use the backend I'll up vote it. Luca D'Alberti actually suggested it first.

Comment: @Oh shoot your right, I didn't think about what will happen if Jack signs in on another phone, i was to busy thinking about Jill signing in. It is a server side value. Change your answer so i can up vote you.

Comment: lol, what you want me to change? Up vote is not a problem, happy to help. Cheers.

Comment: In 99.99% of cases nobody needs to call `.synchronize()` ever. Try to prove that you need to call it: good luck. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this problem Don't use NSUserDefaults to save game levels. Both Matt and Luca D'Alberti are correct when they said.

@Matt
**A registered user's game reach level should be updated to backend API. You should never depend on maintaining them in app itself.**

@Luca D'Alberti
**Actually I think data of this type (purchases) should be saved by your backend. It's not safe to store them locally for many reason: one of them is that you need to delete this key anytime a new user log in and this means that you'll loose all the data of the previous one.**

Upvote either one of them.